# SQL Query - Greater Than with Text Data Type

Tags: sql, oracle, varchar2

I've searched around and couldn't find an answer anywhere.

I'm querying a database that has stored numbers as a `VARCHAR2` data type. 
 I'm trying to find numbers that are greater than `1450000` (`where BI_SO_NBR > '1450000'`), but this doesn't bring back the results I'm expecting.

I'm assuming it's because the value is stored as text and I don't know any way to get around it.

Is there some way to convert the field to a number in my query or some other trick that would work?
Hopefully this makes sense.

I'm fairly new to SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which dbms is this related to? (VARCHAR2 is product specific...)

Comment: @jarlh: doesn't `VARCHAR2` only exist in oracle?

Comment: These conversions are usually DB specific. You need to convert the text to a number and compare that.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I guess it is, but who knows, maybe some other product has it too?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  I believe this is an Oracle database.  The server properties show Oracle 9i/10g/11g as the type.  I use Aqua Data Studios to query multiple databases and just assumed it was a SQL query.  All of the queries I've written (basic stuff) have worked on different types of databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use like this:

```
where to_number(BI_SO_NBR) > 1450000
```

Assuming you are using Oracle database. Also check [To_Number](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm) function

**EDIT:-**

You can try this(*after OP commented that it worked*):

```
where COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(BI_SO_NBR, '^\d+(\.\d+)?')), 0) > 1450000
```

Comment: Shouldn't be: where to_number(BI_SO_NBR) > 1450000?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I just checked the server properties and it says this is an Oracle 9i/10g/11g database.  I use Aqua Data Studio to query the database.  I'm unclear on the difference between Oracle and SQL querying?  I query both type of databases using Aqua Data and my queries seem to work on either type.

Comment: @AdamH:- Whats the query you are trying? The above query will work in Oracle perfectly

Comment: I'm getting an "invalid number" error using the to_number function as mentioned.  All of the values in this field should definitely be numbers (no characters).  I'll try using the length function like Gordon Linoff mentioned below to see if that will help.  It won't let me post the full query in a comment.  It says it is too long.

Comment: @AdamH:- Try this: `where COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(BI_SO_NBR, '^\d+(\.\d+)?')), 0) > 1450000`

Comment: @RahulTripathi: That appears to have worked.  I finally figured out why the to_number function fails by itself.  There is one entry in the BI_SO_NBR column that is not a number (it's actually a "-").  Can you explain how that function works?  I looked up COALESCE and didn't quite understand what it is doing.  It looks like you're telling it to ignore those values, but you don't have the one that we need to ignore ("-") that I can see.  It works, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @AdamH:- I didnt get your question? Do you want me to explain COALESCE?

Comment: @RahulTripathi:  Yes, I'm not sure I understand how it and the REGEXP_SUBSTR functions are working.  Is it replacing any result containing the characters ^\d+(\.\d+)? with a zero?  Sorry, it wouldn't let me open chat to avoid adding so many comments.

Comment: @AdamH: `REGEXP_SUBSTR extends the functionality of the SUBSTR function by letting you search a string for a regular expression pattern.` So in this case the regex is `^\d+(\.\d+)?`. Now to check what the regex is check [this](https://regex101.com/r/gI8cH4/1). BTW your understanding is correct!

Answer (score 2):

If the number is too long to be converted correctly to a number, and it is always an integer with no left padding of zeroes, then you can also do:

```
where length(BI_SO_NBR) > length('1450000') or
      (length(BI_SO_NBR) = length('1450000') and
       BI_SO_NBR > '1450000'
      )
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  This appears to be working.  I can't get the to_number function to work so I'll use this.  Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Oracle, then:

```
where to_number(bi_so_nbr) > 1450000
```

However, there are 2 issues with this:
1. if there is *any* value in `bi_so_nbr` that cannot be converted to a number, this can result in an error
2. the query will not use an index on `bi_so_nbr`, if there is one. You could solve this by creating a function based index, but converting the `varchar2` to number would be a better solution.